# Ways to pack (adjacent) elements of a list into 2-tuples

Tags: haskell

I was wondering if there would be a concise/one-liner way to do the following:

```
pack :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
pack []       = []
pack [_]      = []
pack (x:y:xs) = (x, y) : pack xs
```

Which is the same as:

```
pack' xs = [(x, y) | (x, y, i) <- zip3 xs (tail xs) [0..], even i]
```

I don’t have much against either of these two options, but I was wondering: is there more concise way by combining `(,)` with some other function?

I had assumed there’d be such a way, but it eludes me. So this is just out of curiosity.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

We can easily split the list into two lists with alternating elements with this tidbit ([due to HaskellWiki](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Blow_your_mind))

```
 foldr (\a ~(x,y) -> (a:y,x)) ([],[])
```

All that remains is to combine the lists with `zip`

```
pack :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
pack = uncurry zip . foldr (\a ~(x,y) -> (a:y,x)) ([],[])
```

Comment: Oh, this is neat. I don’t fully understand the mechanics of the lazy match `~`, but it’s clear what the foldr itself is doing. Thanks!

Comment: It also seems to work without the lazy match, which the wiki says is “necessary for efficiency”.

Comment: Dato: To see when the lazy match is necessary, try `take 10 (pack [1...])` with and without the `~`. The lazy match lets you pattern match on the result of an (possibly infinite) computation without waiting for that computation to complete, as you are normally forced to do when matching.

Comment: With the lazy match it is the same as writing `foldr (\a x -> (a:snd x,fst x)) ([],[])`. Normally a pattern like `(x,y)` needs to match before any of the right hand side can be used. The lazy match can be seen as syntactic sugar for a variable (which will always match) and some functions defined based on pattern matching that appear everywhere the variables from the pattern would have. Those functions won't force their argument to weak head normal form until the first of the function applications is forced.

Answer (score 2):

Another one-liner using `LambdaCase` and `Data.List.unfoldr`:

```
pack = unfoldr $ \case (x:y:zs) -> Just ((x,y),zs); _ -> Nothing
```

Something I want occasionally is `splits` -

```
splits :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
splits n = unfoldr $ \case [] -> Nothing ; xs -> Just $ splitAt n xs
```

And given that, `pack` becomes:

```
pack xs = [ (a,b) | [a,b] <- splits 2 xs ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that for `xs = [x1, x2, ..., xn-1, xn]`, we have

```
init xs = [x1, x2, ... , xn-1]
tail xs = [x2, x3, ... , xn  ]
```

leading to

```
zip (init xs) (tail xs) = [(x1, x2), (x2, x3), (x3, x4), ...]
```

and what we want is

```
pack xs                 = [(x1, x2),           (x3, x4), ...]
```

which is easy to get once we have a list of masks

```
cycle [True, False]     = [ True,    False,    True, ...    ]
```

leading to the one-liner

```
pack :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
pack xs = map snd . filter fst . zip (cycle [True, False]) $ zip (init xs) (tail xs)
```

Comment: nope - your version does `pack [1,2,3,4] = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]` rather than `[(1,2),(3,4)]`.

Comment: You could shorten this a little, and avoid the empty list problem, with `pack xs = zip xs (drop 1 xs)`. This still has the issue @rampion mentioned though.

Comment: OK I missed the fact that `(2,3)` etc should not be included. I've updated my answer using the same line of reasoning.

Comment: You can also replace `$ zip (init xs) (tail xs)` with `. liftM2 zip init tail`, thereby making the whole thing point free...

Comment: `zip <$> init <*> tail`, then :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is one line, but:

```
snd $ foldr (\ x (z, ps) -> maybe (Just x, ps) (\y -> (Nothing, (x, y) : ps) z) (Nothing, []) $ xs
```

should be the same as your function.