# Permutations one symbol back, Haskell

Tags: haskell, permutation

How I can permute one symbol back. I have a given string: `abcdpqrs`, where output will be: `badcqpsr`.

My current code:

```
f s = foldr (\a ~(x,y) -> (a:y,x)) ([],[]) s

main :: IO ()
main = do 
    str <- getLine
    print(f str)
```

Evaluating `f "abcdpqrs"` results in

```
("acpr",
 "bdqs")
```

How can this be used to get `"badcqpsr"`?

---

Updated code:

```
rev (a : b : xs) = b : a : rev xs
rev xs = xs
main = do
    n <- getLine
    l <- getContents
    putStr (rev l)
```

When input are 2 strings, `abcdpqrs` and `az` result is `badcqpsra` and `z`. Expected output is `badcqpsr` and `za`. How I can fix it?

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it work? Perhaps the answers to a related question will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/q/27307709/414413

Comment: What would the output be if there were an odd number of elements in the list like in `"abcde"`?

Comment: @Cirdec because I don't now how to start! :(

Comment: @pertpoert `0`? as an integer? That's not possible if the "normal" output has type `String`. *I don't now how to start!* You have to demonstrate that you made some effort towards finding a solution. Otherwise, your question will get closed pretty quickly.

Comment: @pertpoert You could try copying the code from the question I linked and try running it on `"abcdpqrs"`. What does that have to do with your problem? Then try changing the `(x, y) :` part of the third line to something else. What does it do if you put in `"1" : "2" :` instead?

Comment: @pertpoert From what you have now, you might be interested in Daniel Velkov's answer to a related question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3987188/414413 However, you might get much more understanding from tinkering with Dato's `pack` from the first question I linked. http://stackoverflow.com/q/27307709/414413

Comment: @Cirdec I don't understand how I can modify it's code and so I asked a question here. Nobody answered, only comments and helpful minus

Comment: @Cirdec I do not know how to do it and so I asked for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a hint:

```
reverseFirst2 :: [a] -> [a]
reverseFirst2 (x1:x2:xs) = x2:x1:xs
reverseFirst2 xs = xs
```

This reverses the order of the first 2 elements of a list

```
> reverseFirst2 "abcdpqrs"
"bacdpqrs"
```

Can you fill in the `...` below to do the same thing to the remainder of the list?

```
reverseEvery2 :: [a] -> [a]
reverseEvery2 (x1:x2:xs) = x2:x1: ...
reverseEvery2 xs = xs
```

#### Getting input

To get input one line at a time, read the input one line at a time.

```
main = do
    l <- getLine
    print (reverseEvery2 l)
    main
```

The reason you are getting that behavior with `getContents` is the input read from `getContents` includes the newline characters at the end of the lines. It is essentially running

```
rev "abcdpqrs\naz\n" =
    "badcqpsra\n\nz"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but when input are 2 strings, `abcdpqrs` and `az` result is `badcqpsra` and `z`. Expected output is `badcqpsr` and `za`

Comment: @pertpoert Please edit your question with what you have now. A very simple substitution for `...` in `reverseEvery2` results in the expected output for both of those inputs.

Comment: @pertpoert I'd recommend avoiding `getContents` and anything else that performs lazy IO until you understand it well enough to decide for yourself not to use lazy IO.

Comment: `n <- getLine` here is the number of test cases. I need to skip this is number in reverse function