# How can I optimize this shuffle function?

Tags: haskell, shuffle

I am trying to create a generic (type-o-polymophism?) shuffle function with Haskell. I needs to sort a couple of thousand elements in a fraction of a second to be deemed "good enough".

```
evens :: [a] -> [a]
evens l = [l !! i | i <- [0,2..(length l) - 1]]

odds :: [a] -> [a]
odds  l = [l !! i | i <- [1,3..(length l) - 1]]

shuffle :: [a] -> [a]
shuffle s   | length s == 1 = s
        | otherwise = l ++ shuffle r
        where l = evens s
              r = odds s
```

[image]

Comment: What is `skyffla`; is it supposed to be `shuffle`? Can you give us an example of an input and the expected output?

Comment: If `skyffle` is `shuffle`, why are the odds shuffled again? What is your definition of an acceptable "shuffle" function?

Comment: Yeah, skyffla = shuffle. My bad, typo. I will add the definition of my shuffle algorithm.

Comment: `length $ shuffle [1..2000]` already runs in a fraction of a second in ghci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid indexing repeatedly into the same list with `!!` like you do in

```
evens l = [l !! i | i <- [0,2..(length l) - 1]]    -- bad
```

This takes O(n^2) time where n is the length of `l`, since `l !! i` takes O(i) time.

Instead just write something like this:

```
evens [] = []
evens (x:xs) = x : odds xs

odds xs = evens (drop 1 xs)
```

Your `shuffle` itself is fine.

Comment: This did it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

A perfect shuffle can be implemented as

```
perfectShuffle = concat . transpose . chunksOf 2
```

The speed improvements will come from:

1. Not calculating the length of the list repeatedly.
2. Not building up a chain of `(++)` inefficiently, which will require repeated traversals of the list and give an O(n<sup>2</sup>) runtime.

Example output:

```
λ> perfectShuffle [1..10]
[1,3,5,7,9,2,4,6,8,10]
```

`chunksOf` is available in the `split` package. `transpose` is in `Data.List` in base.

Comment: There are a bunch of related ways to partition a list into even and odd elements in the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27307709/414413).

Comment: @Cirdec Sure, but this already shuffles 200,000 elements in less than 0.15 seconds in ghci, which is two orders of magnitude faster than requested.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I forgot to mention that I follow a specific algorithm. See my edited question for the algorithm.

Comment: @Entalpi Yeah, that was rather important information to include in your question.